# Querystring parameter in content search webpart ignored when using refiners

Tags: content-search-web-part, query-string, refiner

I've put a content search webpart on a page together with some refiners. The items in the content search webpart are filtered by a query string parameter (name: tag)

```
path:"https://abcdefgh.sharepoint.com/Onderwijs/Opleidingen/opleidingswerkruimte"  (FileExtension:doc OR FileExtension:docx OR FileExtension:xls OR FileExtension:xlsx OR FileExtension:ppt OR FileExtension:pptx OR FileExtension:pdf) (IsDocument:"True" OR contentclass:"STS_ListItem") {?RefinableString00:{QueryString.tag}}
```

this works fine until I use one of the refiners, the results are getting 'refined' but when I click 'show all' again in the refiner section no data is show.

The url changes to something like this:

https://abcdefgh.sharepoint.com/subsite/SitePages/Overzicht.aspx?tag=BM#Default=%7B%22k%22%3A%22%22%7D#16b97be2-6fa5-4b3c-9402-a05f9bc4c22a=%7B%22k%22%3A%22%22%7D

any help here?

Answer (score 0):

Using SharePoint 2010 Search Query String Parameters 
http://t.co/RmsjprToe5

Answer (score 0):

You can confirm what value the query is getting from the `{QueryString.tag}`. First go to the page, refine and then remove the refiners. Edit the content search webpart and go into the query builder. Click on the test tab and expand the more options version. At the bottom you will see the value the tag is returning. My guess is that it will look like.

```
BM#Default=%7B%22k%22%3A%22%22%7D#16b97be2-6fa5-4b3c-9402-a05f9bc4c22a=%7B%22k%22%3A%22%22%7D
```

Because the QueryString.tag code doesn't know that a parameter value should end at the hash portion of the url.

I've worked around this by adding an & to the end of the parameter. I'm not sure how the link and its parameter value are generated, but you need to have the initial url look like

```
https://abcdefgh.sharepoint.com/subsite/SitePages/Overzicht.aspx?tag=BM&
```